# jTable not showing new row content after MySQL INSERT with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, jquery-jtable

I have a little jTable that shows a list of records pulled from my local database using node.js with express-generator and mysql. I can show, create, edit and delete records in/from my table just fine.

My problem is that when I add a new record using my jTable, it creates an empty row in my jTable and doesn't populate it with the newly added data unless I refresh the page. This is weird because it successfully updates the row in the jTable when I edit and delete it using the jTable as well.

Can anyone see why this is happening?
(I excluded the edit and delete code since those work properly)

**tbl_bar structure**

```
rowID = INT, PK, AI
rowName = VARCHAR, UQ
rowOrder = INT (for future row organization)
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:     'localhost',
    user:     'root',
    password: 'password'
});

// Select which database to use
connection.query('USE db_foo;');

/*********************/
/***** SHOW ROWS *****/
/*********************/
// Retrieves all rows and sends them to the jTable for display
router.showRows = function (request, response) {
    // Query tbl_bar and return the ordered result/s
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_bar ORDER BY rowOrder;', function (error, result) {
        if (error) response.send({ Result: "ERROR", Message: "Error getting rows" });
        else response.send({ Result: "OK", Records: result });
    });
}

/**********************/
/***** CREATE ROW *****/
/**********************/
// Function for inserting new row into tbl_bar
function insertRow(data, response) {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO tbl_bar SET ?', data, function(error, result) {
        if (error) response.send({ Result: "ERROR", Message: "Error adding row" });
        else response.send({ Result: "OK", Records: result });
    });
}
// Adds a new row to tbl_bar
router.createRow = function (request, response) {
    var query = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request.body));

    // Check if tbl_bar contains any rows
    connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM tbl_bar', function (error, result) {
        if (error) response.send({ Result: "ERROR", Message: "Error getting rows" });
        else {
            var data = {
                rowName: query.rowName
            };

            // If tbl_bar contains no rows, make rowOrder 1
            if (result[0].rowCount === 0) {
                data['rowOrder'] = 1;
                insertRow(data, response);
            } else {
                // Get the highest rowOrder to determine order of newly added row
                connection.query('SELECT rowOrder FROM tbl_bar ORDER BY rowOrder DESC LIMIT 1', function (error, result) {
                    if (error) response.send({ Result: "ERROR", Message: "Error getting rows" });
                    else {
                        data['rowOrder'] = result[0].rowOrder + 1;
                        insertRow(data, response);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

/*************************/
/***** GET HOME PAGE *****/
/*************************/
router.get('/', function (request, response, next) {
    response.render('index', { title: 'My jTable' });
});

// Event listeners
router.post('/showRows', router.showRows);
router.post('/createRow', router.createRow);

module.exports = router;
```

**table.js**

```
function populateTable() {
    $('#container').jtable({
        title: 'My jTable',
        paging: false,
        messages: {
            addNewRecord: 'Add a New Row'
        },
        deleteConfirmation: function(data) {
            data.deleteConfirmMessage = 'Delete Row: ' + data.record.rowName + '?';
        },
        actions: {
            listAction:   '/showRows',
            createAction: '/createRow'
        },
        fields: {
            rowID: {
                key:    true,
                list:   false,
                create: false,
                edit:   false
            },
            rowName: {
                title:  'Name',
                list:   true,
                create: true,
                edit:   true
            },
            rowOrder: {
                list:   false,
                create: false,
                edit:   true
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {    
    populateTable();
    $('#container').jtable('load');
});
```

**index.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    |     
    title My jTable
    |     
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='javascripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css')
    |     
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='javascripts/jtable.2.4.0/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css')
    |     
    script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js')
    |     
    script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js')
    |     
    script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/jtable.2.4.0/jquery.jtable.min.js')
    |     
    script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/table.js')
  |   
  body
    #container
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on a child table I came across the same problem, except this time I was able to find a solution. In order to get the new row to display its data, I needed to reload the jTable with the [recordAdded](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Events#event-recordAdded) event.
It's a shame that I can't keep the cool row fade-in effect though.

```
recordAdded: function (event, data) {
    $('#container').jtable('reload');
}
```

For my child tables I used

```
recordAdded: function (event, data) {
    $('.jtable-child-table-container').jtable('reload');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code maybe you can try to change this line in your insertRow function:

`else response.send({ Result: "OK", Records: result });`

To

`else response.send({ Result: "OK", Record: result });`

---

I had the same problem (jtable not showing data in the new added row) but with PHP.

The problem was the format of the JSON response of my PHP page.

This format (1 element array) does not work as intended:

`{"Result":"OK","Record":[{"id_documento":"96","id_prodotto":"27","qta":"5"}]}`

This format does work as intended, with the fade-in effect:

`{"Result":"OK","Record":{"id_documento":"96","id_prodotto":"27","qta":"5"}}`

In PHP, the difference was this (wrong way):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $rows[]=$row;
}
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Record'] = $rows;
```

to (correct way):

```
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Record'] = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Hope this helps.